# Android PlaceJSONParser

Tags: android, json, google-maps-api-3

I am following a guide involving Google Maps API and I am trying to retrive a place search and show it on the Map in my app but in the tutorial it shows me this code

```
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>> {

    JSONObject jObject;

    // Invoked by execute() method of this object
    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
        PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
            places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }
        return places;
    }
}
```

But I get error on "PlaceJSONParser" and "parse"

Comment: are you getting the jsonData, seems its null

Comment: This is what the tutorial said, also the PlaceJSONParser shouldnt be giving errors nevertheless. "Cannot resolve symbol "PlaceJSONParser""

Comment: Try the URL of the json request in a browser to make sure that you are creating the request correctly.

Comment: Which tutorial did you follow? There is something wrong with the `PlaceJSONParser` object.